# Almost Repeating Myself

Tags: go, refactoring

> **Combinitorial Explosion** You have lots of code that does almost the same thing.. but with tiny variations in data or behavior. This can be difficult to refactor-- perhaps using generics or an interpreter? - Jeff Atwood via [Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/)

In this case it is not lots of code, but it is still bugging me. I have a shared problem, that is when trying to connect to an IP, if it fails, I should retry with the next IP.

I have one function which generates a producer for NSQ:

```
//Since we are in a critical system, we try with each IP until we get a producer
var err error
for i, success := 0, false; i < len(ips) && !success; i++ {
    publisher, err = nsq.NewProducer(ips[i], nsq.NewConfig())
    if err == nil {
        success = true
    }
}
```

The other function that almost shares the same code is one which takes a NSQ consumer and connects it:

```
var err error
for i, success := 0, false; i < len(ips) && !success; i++ {
    err = consumer.ConnectToNSQD(ips[i])
    if err == nil {
        success = true
    }
}
```

I would like to get rid of this almost repeated code without sacrificing legibility. Ideas?

Comment: that will not be a good idea I think. IP layer is too low for a client library of a network service, thinking a distributed system like replication and sharding.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://play.golang.org/p/QeFH1gj6NA

Comment: Please no! Each loop is clear, it does one thing, it is very short and you do some error handling which is okay. Don't combine different stuff here. Assume the following: In 6 month your `ConnectToNSQD` gets a new error code `FailedButPleaseRetryIn15ms`. Now you may want to retry the same IP after some sleep, but only in **one** of these functions. IMHO "DRY" as main principle to follow brainless is dead ugly. I like the negated form much better "Do not write un-DRY code". Your two loops are DRY like a good martini.

Comment: @Volker interesting point, although I do not agree with your justification based on a non-existing requirement. However, we can discuss the necessity of creating a function, because it is true that each loop do one thing and it is clear what they do.

Comment: @Volker I think the advantages of extracting that loop to a function are twofold: 1) Increases readability and 2) makes testing easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it backwards. Your solution should follow the shape of the problem, not the shape of a particular solution. There's nothing in the solution that's worth refactoring. It's just going to add pointless complexity.

For example,

```
package main

import "github.com/nsqio/go-nsq"

// NewProducer is nsq.NewProducer with retries of an address list.
func NewProducer(addrs []string, config *nsq.Config) (producer *nsq.Producer, err error) {
    if len(addrs) == 0 {
        addrs = append(addrs, "")
    }
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        producer, err = nsq.NewProducer(addr, config)
        if err == nil {
            break
        }
    }
    return producer, err
}

// ConnectToNSQD is nsq.ConnectToNSQD with retries of an address list.
func ConnectToNSQD(c *nsq.Consumer, addrs []string) (err error) {
    if len(addrs) == 0 {
        addrs = append(addrs, "")
    }
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        err = c.ConnectToNSQD(addr)
        if err == nil {
            break
        }
    }
    return err
}

func main() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
var publisher *nsq.Producer

connectToWorkingIP(ips, func(ip string) error {
    var err error
    publisher, err = nsq.NewProducer(ip, nsq.NewConfig())
    return err
})

connectToWorkingIP(ips, func(ip string) error {
    return consumer.ConnectToNSQD(ip)
})


func connectToWorkingIP(ips []string, f func(string) error) {
    for i, success := 0, false; i < len(ips) && !success; i++ {
        err := f(ips[i])
        if err == nil {
            success = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "The scope of an identifier denoting a constant, type, variable, or function (but not method) declared at top level (outside any function) is the package block."  The `publisher` package level variable is not a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, but it was just a gist, since i have no idea, from which function the top part should be called